# Inserting fields for mail merge and space bar repeats field instead of adding space

Tags: microsoft-word, merge, label

Inserting fields into Word doc to create labels for mail merge. When I click on first name and insert, it does. I hit the space bar to put a space between first name field and last name field, but hitting the space bar does not add a space it repeats the first name. What am I doing wrong?